htaccess: Удаление слеша с конца url
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

Работает, но хотелось бы сделать все за одно 301 перенаправление
Выставлено правило
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

Перенаправляет с http на https. Возможно ли к данному правило, добавить правило на удаление слеша с конца url?

Вы не сможете сэкономить строки, в этом примере нужны AND|OR, чтобы избежать бесконечного редиректа, но AND и OR в RewriteCond работают через новую строку.
Указанный вариант - самый простой. Можно сделать два Cond и одно Rule, но там чуть сложное регулярное выражение, я не могу его построить правильно.

Я смогу вам ответить сразу же, как узнаю ответ на другой вопрос ) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1596537/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5-regexp-htaccess
