Необязательный символ в конце Regexp (.htaccess)
Я хочу добиться, чтобы одним выражением RewriteRule происходил редирект по двум условиям.
Если http, или в конце есть /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

Но конструкция ^(.*)/?$ вносит конечный слэш в группу $1. Как его отделить?
пример в тестере .htaccess

может неактуально уже, но все же
потому что группа (.*) жадная и она заберет к себе закрывающий слеш
если надо исключить его из группы, то необходимо так и указывать
RewriteRule ^([^/])/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

PS это конечно под конкретный пример. То есть для http://a.com/yyy/zzz/ уже не сработает

А не проще сделать не жадным то, что в группе? И мне кажется вы модификатор * в группе потеряли, это же один знак только будет.
